# OPC DA to UA gateway

Tags: gateway, opc, opc-ua, opc-da

We are trying to communicate two implementations,
one based into OPC DA (the server works into SCADA and its kind of a "black box", so all we an do is to subscribe to the OPC DA stream)

We are using thingsboard as main application for data visualization, bu this doesnt support OPC DA (as it is a too old technology), however thingsboard can flawlessly use OPC UA, mqtt, websocket, rpc, and many more,
so we need to figure out a way to subscribe to this OPC DA and then stream this exact data as OPC UA, MQTT or even Websocket

I've being researching into internet but honestly i'm kind of lost about how OPC UA and DA works.

I'll really appreciate it if you have any usefull link to a software, code library or so on that could make this conversion.

we are working with Python and Node js, In case there is any code library that could help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Node-RED? There's some OPC DA support https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-opc-da

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this: https://www.unified-automation.com/products/wrapper-and-proxy/uagateway.html

I am not affiliated with Unified Automation.

Comment: Thanks! i'll be revieving this software and talk to my partner, be right back to give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, I suggest Rapid SCADA Communicator v6.x. Since the recent release it works as OPC DA -> OPC UA gateway. This is an open source project available on [GitHub](https://github.com/RapidScada/scada-v6).